# Consuming file contents with Clojure's core.async

Tags: clojure, core.async

I'm trying to use Clojure's [`core.async`](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/) library to consume/process lines from a file. When my code executes an `IOException: Stream closed` is throw. Below is a REPL session that reproduces the same problem as in my code:

```
(require '[clojure.core.async :as async])
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

; my real code is a bit more involved with calls to drop, map, filter
; following line-seq
(def lines
  (with-open [reader (io/reader "my-file.txt")]
    (line-seq reader)))

(def ch
  (let [c (async/chan)]
    (async/go
      (doseq [ln lines]
        (async/>! c ln))
      (async/close! c))
    c))

; line that causes the error
; java.io.IOException: Stream closed
(async/<!! ch)
```

Since its is my first time doing something like this (async + file), maybe I have some misconceptions about how it should work. Can someone clarify what is the correct approach to send file lines into a channels pipeline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the `with-open` statement.  The file is closed as soon as this scope is exited.  So, you open a `line-seq` and then close the file before reading any lines.

You will be better off for most files using the `slurp` function:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

(def file-as-str   (slurp "my-file.txt"))
(def lines         (str/split-lines file-as-str))
```

See:

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/slurp

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split-lines

Comment: I see... I wanted to avoid loading the entire file's content into memory at once because it can be a big one. That is why I thought about using with-open/line-seq combo. With this restriction (file size) in mind, is there something that I can do?

Comment: It seems like clojure needs a way to tie an open resource into a lazy seq to keep it from being closed until the lazy seq is consumed. I'm also trying to do line-by-line processing on very large files and running into this without putting all the processing within the `with-open`

Answer (score 6):

As [@Alan pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38341037/5044950), your definition of `lines` closes the file without reading all of its lines, because [`line-seq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/line-seq) returns a lazy sequence. If you expand your use of the [`with-open`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-open) macro...

```
(macroexpand-1
 '(with-open [reader (io/reader "my-file.txt")]
    (line-seq reader)))
```

... you get this:

```
(clojure.core/let [reader (io/reader "my-file.txt")]
  (try
    (clojure.core/with-open []
      (line-seq reader))
    (finally
      (. reader clojure.core/close))))
```

You can fix this problem by closing the file after you finish reading from it, rather than immediately:

```
(def ch
  (let [c (async/chan)]
    (async/go
      (with-open [reader (io/reader "my-file.txt")]
        (doseq [ln (line-seq reader)]
          (async/>! c ln)))
      (async/close! c))
    c))
```

Comment: So it was really a misunderstanding of mine... I thought that `with-open` would somehow "retain" the opened reader until it was exausted. I'll accept Alan's answer since he pointed the problem first and your's is built upon his. :-) But thanks very much for clarifying things even further.